# Attribut error when using contextvar in python 3.10

Tags: python, python-contextvars

When running this code below I got an

> AttributError: `__enter__`

I looked around with no success.

```
import contextvars

# Création d'une variable de contexte
user_context = contextvars.ContextVar("user")

# Définition de la valeur de la variable dans le contexte actuel
with user_context.set("utilisateur123"):
    # Cette valeur est accessible à l'intérieur de ce bloc
    print(user_context.get())  # Affiche "utilisateur123"

# En dehors du bloc, la valeur redevient celle par défaut (None)
print(user_context.get())  # Affiche "None"
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: A context variable is not a context manager, you can't use it with `with`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confusing the two uses of the word "context" here - the fact is that contextvars, as provided in the module with that name, do not work as Python contexts  - the type of objects that work in the `with` statement.
(Although such an interface *would* make sense, and I do implement it in my personal, unfinished, project at https://github.com/jsbueno/extracontext )

The correct way to execute some code in a separate context, is by containing it in a function and call it by using the `.run()` method in a context:

```
import contextvars

# Création d'une variable de contexte
user_context = contextvars.ContextVar("user")

def my_code():
    """this function will run in an independent copy of the outter context"""
    # Définition de la valeur de la variable dans le contexte actuel
    user_context.set("utilisateur123"):
    # Cette valeur est accessible à l'intérieur de ce bloc
    print(user_context.get())  # Affiche "utilisateur123"

my_context = contextvars.copy_context()
my_context.run(my_code)

# En dehors du bloc, la valeur redevient celle par défaut (None)
print(user_context.get())  # Affiche "None"
```